# App that has to work in background and push itself to foreground

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on a App and since I have never done Android Development before I need some help. I have a app that talks with a API. The API is pull-base, meaning that if the Server wants to send something to me, it pushes it into my message box and I have to ask for it.

What my app has to do is to check for new messages in every 15 seconds and start another Activity.

One more requirment is that the app has to work in the background, when a new message comes in, the app needs to push itself to the foreground (Dont worry about usability, its not a app for popular consumtion).

First I had a AsyncTask but if you start a activity from a AsyncTask in the background it does not push the app to the foreground.

What design should I use for this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm. I'm actually not sure there's a method for pushing an app to the foreground (such a thing could be easily abused, e.g., popup spam ads that keep pushing themselves to the foreground).  What DOES work, though, is a notification, which the user can see and click on.  So the background thread (which could be Asyntask or Timer.schduleAtFixedRate or AlarmManager set to go off every 15 seconds, to name three) sees that it has something for the user to see, then uses NotificationManager to put up something for the user to click on, which launches the activity.

Comment: @JamieB I acctually think Notifications would be ok but I have not all the design power for the app.

Comment: If you can't find a way to push the app back to the foreground, another idea might be to do it as a widget.  It would be easy enough to have a live widget running which can update its desktop appearance without the user having to do anything.  e.g., when a message is received, it simply displays it, like stock tickers or weather apps.  Still not exactly what you want though, since the user still has to be on the right screen to see it change.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider AlarmManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

To resume your activity rather than starting a new one, you may need to play with activity properties like "singleTop".

Another useful thing to know about, even though you may not need it for now, is Service:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html